# Compare dates google sheets script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am trying to set up a script (for google sheets) where once I introduce a date on the 2nd column, if it turns out to be sooner than tomorrow (or in the past) it returns a message box with a certain message. This is what I tried so far, but it seems I'm doing something wrong in comparing the dates.

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var today = new Date(); 
  var minDate = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+(today.getDate()+1);

  if (e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.value.toString()<minDate){
    Browser.msgBox('WARNING MESSAGE...');
  }
}
```

Any ideas of why it's not working?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Not accepting dates sooner than tomorrow**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!='Sheet1')return;
    var today=new Date(); 
  var tomorrow=new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),today.getDate()+1).valueOf();
  var setDate=new Date(e.range.getValue()).valueOf();
  if (e.range.columnStart==2 && setDate<tomorrow){
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("WARNING...I don't except dates sooner than tomorrow.")
  }
}
```

Lately, I've been having trouble using e.value and I often find that just going and getting e.range.getValue() while a bit more time consuming actually works better.

You can use valueOf() or getTime() to get the date value as number of milliseconds

[Javascript Date Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Yes, thanks! In the end, I decided to work with all the dates as milliseconds and managed to compare them perfectly.

Comment: I find that to be preferable most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the Date JavaScript object to compare the dates. Since doing it with strings just does it alphabetically. That could look something like this for you example

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var minDate = new Date();
    minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1); // Add one to the day
    minDate.setMonth(minDate.getMonth() + 1); // Add one to the month
    if (e.range.columnStart == 2 && new Date(e.value.toString()) < minDate) {
        Browser.msgBox('WARNING MESSAGE...');
    }
}
```

This will parse the string date that you got from e.value into a JavaScript date object allowing it to be compared with minDate.